# Move slow `udev-configure-printer` from systemd boot to after login prompt

Tags: boot, printing, services, systemd, cups-lpd

I've been tweaking my boot speed today. The first step was to remove:

```
      6.194s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

To remove it I used:

```
systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

And now my boot time shows:

```
$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 3.407s (kernel) + 8.356s (userspace) = 11.764s
```

The network still works ok so it appears no harm has come from the change.

Next on the `systemd-analyze blame` list is:

```
      5.467s udev-configure-printer@-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb3-3\x2d3-3\x2d3.1.service
```

I only use my printer a couple times a month and I certainly don't need it during the boot up phase. My question is; how do I move CUPS initialization out of the boot sequence into a post boot environment like **Startup Applications** or `/etc/rc.local` or whatever place makes sense?

Or can systemd be told to load the service after login screen appears? Or told to simply wait 15 seconds before loading the service?

---

## What I tried

Using the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21830670/systemd-start-service-after-specific-service) I set the target to be after the login prompt. I did this by editing `/lib/systemd/system/udev-configure-printer.service` to look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Automatic USB/Bluetooth printer setup (%i)
# July 29, 2017 - Move from startup (5 seconds time) to after login screen
After=lightdm.service

[Service]
#Type=simple
Type=forking
GuessMainPID=true
ExecStart=/lib/udev/udev-configure-printer add %I
# This ExecStop would be useful to disable the print queue when ippusbxd
# crashes or gets killed, but in the case that ippusbxd does not get started
# at all during the process run by ExecStart (printer does not support
# IPP-over-USB) ExecStop gets run immediately making a printer getting
# disabled again right after it getting enabled or set up
# ExecStop=/lib/udev/udev-configure-printer remove %I
```

Even after rebooting twice to confirm speeds, the boot time went from 11 seconds to 16 seconds.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @x0a I have four USB ports on the laptop. I think the solution is to make the one connected to the USB 3.0 7 port hub (that has printer attached) off-line during boot phase. Then in cron or /etc/rc.local bring it on-line after log-in. At that stage udev will trigger systemd to initialize CUPS. A few years ago I spent 6 weeks in EnhanceIO to make the laptop boot from 45 seconds to 16 seconds and LibreOffice load from 17 seconds to 4 seconds but what is required here to shave 11 seconds down to 9 seconds doesn't seem worthwhile right now. Sorry :(