# Ubuntu takes ~1:20 to boot

Tags: boot

My Ubuntu installation is taking more than a minute to boot... I've had this problem for quite some time. I've already turned off secure boot (I always get that "PKCS#7 not signed with a trusted key" error). This is the output of `systemd-analyze blame`:

```
         16.818s systemd-journal-flush.service
         16.519s systemd-udevd.service
         16.064s snapd.service
         13.623s dev-loop21.device
         13.546s dev-loop10.device
         13.442s dev-loop22.device
         13.252s dev-loop13.device
         13.067s dev-loop14.device
         13.060s dev-loop23.device
         12.996s dev-loop3.device
         12.986s dev-loop6.device
         12.960s dev-loop18.device
         12.954s dev-loop16.device
         12.951s dev-loop15.device
         12.949s dev-loop12.device
         12.882s dev-loop24.device
         12.862s dev-loop27.device
         12.822s dev-loop17.device
         12.413s dev-loop25.device
         12.337s ModemManager.service
         12.336s dev-loop26.device
         12.261s dev-loop9.device
         12.116s dev-loop7.device
         12.103s networkd-dispatcher.service
         12.077s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
         11.930s dev-loop20.device
         11.809s gpu-manager.service
         11.692s dev-loop19.device
         11.512s dev-loop11.device
         11.393s dev-loop5.device
         11.140s dev-loop2.device
         11.137s dev-loop0.device
         10.934s dev-loop8.device
         10.700s dev-loop4.device
         10.029s dev-loop1.device
          9.770s NetworkManager.service
          7.673s grub-common.service
          6.692s bluetooth.service
          6.331s udisks2.service
          6.253s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1313.mount
          6.207s accounts-daemon.service
          5.738s wpa_supplicant.service
          5.508s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-63.mount
          5.212s systemd-logind.service
          5.060s pppd-dns.service
          4.827s snap-core18-1049.mount
          4.796s snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-132.mount
          4.706s rsyslog.service
          4.699s speech-dispatcher.service
          4.686s apport.service
          4.414s snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-81.mount
          4.347s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-67.mount
          3.896s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-88.mount
          3.840s tlp.service
          3.790s apparmor.service
          3.510s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-352.mount
          3.238s snap-google\x2dplay\x2dmusic\x2ddesktop\x2dplayer-70.mount
          2.957s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-260.mount
          2.800s networking.service
          2.748s snap-core18-1066.mount
          2.676s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          2.558s thermald.service
          2.486s snap-discord-93.mount
          2.287s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1198.mount
          2.242s gdm.service
          2.156s apport-autoreport.service
          2.125s snap-core-7270.mount
          2.119s systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
          2.028s setvtrgb.service
          2.009s systemd-modules-load.service
          1.990s user@121.service
          1.972s snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-77.mount
          1.903s keyboard-setup.service
          1.853s snap-gnome\x2dlogs-45.mount
          1.835s snap-netbeans-6.mount
          1.735s systemd-backlight@leds:dell::kbd_backlight.service
          1.731s snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-296.mount
          1.649s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-90.mount
          1.438s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
          1.434s systemd-random-seed.service
          1.314s snap-core-7169.mount
          1.103s avahi-daemon.service
          1.016s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-95.mount
           906ms plymouth-read-write.service
           898ms snap-netbeans-10.mount
           881ms swapfile.swap
           864ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-292.mount
           858ms packagekit.service
           843ms snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-143.mount
           759ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-406.mount
           655ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-61.mount
           587ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-100.mount
           586ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
           585ms ufw.service
           579ms systemd-journald.service
           406ms polkit.service
           398ms systemd-resolved.service
           370ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-6030\x2d6C29.service
           363ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           265ms snapd.socket
           218ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-57.mount
           214ms systemd-hostnamed.service
           180ms systemd-remount-fs.service
           174ms systemd-sysctl.service
           173ms kmod-static-nodes.service
           150ms systemd-update-utmp.service
           146ms upower.service
           115ms bolt.service
           104ms user@1000.service
            87ms nvidia-persistenced.service
            73ms dev-hugepages.mount
            70ms dev-mqueue.mount
            69ms colord.service
            51ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
            39ms snapd.seeded.service
            37ms rtkit-daemon.service
            10ms alsa-restore.service
             6ms kerneloops.service
             5ms boot-efi.mount
             4ms dns-clean.service
             3ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
             3ms ureadahead-stop.service
             3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
             3ms sys-kernel-config.mount
             2ms systemd-user-sessions.service
             2ms console-setup.service
             1ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
```

And [this](https://pastebin.com/FcGJLRC2) is the output of `dmesg`. As you can see, there are some errors, including multiple PKCS errors.

I was also asked for the output of `systemd-analyze critical chain`, so here it is: https://pastebin.com/VBtjjThw.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete, properly formattted output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain`

Comment: @user535733 edited

Comment: `run-user-121.mount @1min 303ms` looks suspicious, and in the wrong place in the boot order.

Comment: @user535733 what command? also what is wrong with that and what I should I do to fix it?

Comment: For some tips: https://askubuntu.com/questions/958838/ubuntu-16-04-3-still-takes-1-5-minutes-to-boot-after-successful-clone-to-ssd-a and: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012912/systemd-logs-journalctl-are-too-large-and-slow